# ¿Como puedo actualizar campos de tabla pivot con SYNC laravel?

Tags: laravel

¿Como puedo actualizar campos de tabla pivot con SYNC laravel?

Hola,

No estoy seguro si estoy planteando bien mi pregunta, pero anexo lo que tengo

Quiero registrar un nuevo pago y a la ves actualizar el ROL de el usuario que lo registro.

Intento registrar el pago asi:

```
 $payment = payment::create($request->all());
```

Un dd de ese codigo me regresa lo siguiente:

```
App\Payment {#1410 ▼
  #fillable: array:5 [▶]
  #connection: "mysql"
  #table: "payments"
  #primaryKey: "id"
  #keyType: "int"
  +incrementing: true
  #with: []
  #withCount: []
  #perPage: 15
  +exists: true
  +wasRecentlyCreated: true
  #attributes: array:8 [▶]
  #original: array:8 [▼
    "user_id" => "14"
    "tpaid_id" => "2"
    "vouche" => "5345435"
    "description" => "543535"
    "status" => "pass"
    "updated_at" => "2020-10-22 23:00:34"
    "created_at" => "2020-10-22 23:00:34"
    "id" => 108
  ]
```

Hasta ahi todo bien, porque si lo agrega en la base de datos.

Mi necesidad es actualizar el tipo de rol de un usuario en específico.

```
    $role = Role::find($roles); //puedo buscar el tipo de rol
```

Ahora, tengo que buscar el $user_id en la tabla role_user, que es
donde estan la tabla pivot

modelo payment

```
    <?php

namespace App;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Caffeinated\Shinobi\Concerns\HasRolesAndPermissions;

class Payment extends Model
{
    use Notifiable, HasRolesAndPermissions;

    protected $fillable=['tpaid_id','user_id','vouche','description','status'];
    
    public function tipopago(){
        return $this->hasOne(Tpaid::class, 'id','tpaid_id');
    }
    public function usuario(){
        return $this->hasOne(User::class, 'id','user_id');
    }

}
```

modelo USER

```
    <?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use App\Notifications\UserResetPassword;
use App\Notifications\VerifyEmails;
use Caffeinated\Shinobi\Concerns\HasRolesAndPermissions;

class User extends Authenticatable implements MustVerifyEmail
{
    use Notifiable, HasRolesAndPermissions;


    public function sendEmailVerificationNotification()
    {
        $this->notify(new VerifyEmails);
    }

    public function sendPasswordResetNotification($token)
    {
        $this->notify(new UserResetPassword($token));
    }

    
    public function payments(){
      return $this->belongsTo(Payment::class, 'id','user_id');
    }

    
    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */

     //Aqui son los datos que se dan de alta para interactuar con el formulario y Contorlador
     
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];
}
```

Anexo el modelo ROLES del paquete shinobi/caffeinate

```
    <?php

namespace Caffeinated\Shinobi\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Caffeinated\Shinobi\Concerns\HasPermissions;
use Caffeinated\Shinobi\Contracts\Role as RoleContract;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsToMany;

class Role extends Model implements RoleContract
{
    use HasPermissions;
    
    /**
     * The attributes that are fillable via mass assignment.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = ['name', 'slug', 'description', 'special'];

    /**
     * Create a new Role instance.
     * 
     * @param  array  $attributes
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct(array $attributes = [])
    {
        parent::__construct($attributes);

        $this->setTable(config('shinobi.tables.roles'));
    }

    /**
     * Roles can belong to many users.
     *
     * @return Model
     */
    public function users(): BelongsToMany
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(config('auth.model') ?: config('auth.providers.users.model'))->withTimestamps();
    }

    /**
     * Determine if role has permission flags.
     * 
     * @return bool
     */
    public function hasPermissionFlags(): bool
    {
        return ! is_null($this->special);
    }

    /**
     * Determine if the requested permission is permitted or denied
     * through a special role flag.
     * 
     * @return bool
     */
    public function hasPermissionThroughFlag(): bool
    {
        if ($this->hasPermissionFlags()) {
            return ! ($this->special === 'no-access');
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

¿Es posible hacerlo de otra forma y utilizando transacciones?

Saludos

Comment: `$roles  = array($request->role_id);   $users  = array($payment->user_id); `,        `$user->roles()->attach($users, $roles);` y me da el siguiente error, `SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '0' in 'field list' (SQL: insert into `role_user` (`role_id`, `user_id`, `0`) values (19, ?, 12))` . Realice cambios y lo ejecuto asi. Creo que no estoy entendiendo el metodo.

Comment: Hola, si esta recibiendo,  [te anexo un DD,](https://prnt.sc/v4zmxj)

Comment: Y por qué no intentas hacer algo así: https://pastebin.com/8BPfqeLx

Comment: Actualice mi pregunta, con tu respuesta me aclaraste mi duda. Te agradezco ese apoyo, sin embargo necesito es buscar el user_id en la tabla pivot para poder actualizar el role_id en dicha tabla

Comment: ufs sí, leí un rato la documentación del paquete shinobi  y conseguí la solución.         $roles = auth()->user()->assignRoles($roles);, quiero darte los puntos a ti, porque tu respuesta me pudo aclarar muchas cosas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Según la documentación de [shinobi](https://caffeinatedpackages.com/guide/packages/shinobi.html#usage), si quieres actualizar el rol de un usuario puedes hacerlo de la siguiente manera:

```
auth()->user()->assignRoles('role-1', 'role-2');
```

Dicho método puede recibe el `slug` de cada rol que quieras asignarle al usuario.